# Is it possible to add an OR to a selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I current have a jQuery delegate that does something to all of the `input` selectors that are not `submit input` selectors.  How do you add an **OR** so that it also handles another type like `select`?

Current function:

```
$('#test_form').delegate("input:not([id*='_submit'])", 'blur', function(event) {
  // Does something
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for un-reasonable downvotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comma `,` in selector behaves like `OR`:

```
// -------------------------------------------------v
$("#test_form").delegate("input:not([id*='_submit']), select", "blur", function(e) {
    // Does something
});
```

You can read more about multiple selector here:

- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: So just add a comma, in case someone doesn't notice.

Comment: I'm getting a `selector is undefined [Break On This Error] elem[ type ]();` error when I add `$("#test_form").delegate("input:not([id*='_submit']), select:not([id*='_test')". "blur", function(e) {..});` in that format

Comment: @persistence Because you are using `.` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

so try

```
$('input[type!="submit"]')
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fF6GA/

### update:

or let's say:

```
$('#test_form').delegate('input[type!="submit"], selector', 'blur', function(event) {
});
```

ALSO:

maybe, `on()` is better choice.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. He already has a selector to not include type=submit. He wants to know if he can use multiple selectors as an 'OR'

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can use the  multiple selector separated by comma

e.g.

```
$('#test_form').delegate("input:not([id*='_submit'], select)", 'blur', function(event) {
  // Does something
});
```